# how to separate post in a frame in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to put each post in my word press site inside a frame, & I use the default theme ( twentyeleven ). I want my posts be in a square. Like this theme :

[See the example theme](http://wp-themes.com/suffusion/?TB_iframe=true&width=1153&height=542)

So, each post be in a frame ( porder in all 4th sides ) like above link.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this to your CSS:

```
.post {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px 15px 1em 15px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This will put each post in its own "block". You can change the background and
border colors by changing the values in the above CSS snippet.

Comment: thanks, You mean I need to put this code in style.css ? I will try it